# cambiar nombre terminal mac

Tags: shell, macos

queria saber si hay forma de quitar todo el nombre que aparece en el terminal, utiliza mucho espacio. lo tengo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me gustaría que quedara algo como esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puede seguir estos pasos:

1. Abrir la terminal.
2. Para cambiar el Primary hostmame, ejemplo: ***mimac.domain.com***

   ```
    sudo scutil --set HostName <new host name
   ```
3. Para cambiar el Bonjour hostname, ejemplo: mimac.local

   ```
   sudo scutil --set LocalHostName <new host name>
   ```
4. Para cambiar el nombre del computador.

   ```
   sudo scutil --set ComputerName <new name>
   ```
5. Vaciar cache del DNS:

   ```
   dscacheutil -flushcache
   ```
6. Reiniciar el equipo.

Si tiene alguna duda, puede leer este articulo: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/flame-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Setting-the-Mac-hostname-or-computer-name-from-the-terminal.html

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir a tu fichero `.bash_profile` y introducir está linea:

- `export PS1="\W \$ "` te muestra `~ $`
- `export PS1="\W jean \$ "` te muestra `~ jean $`

Después de guardar esta linea tienes que reiniciar el terminal.

Comment: eh ejecutado sudo vi .bash_profile añade la primera linea pero sigue saliendo el nombre completo :(

Comment: Haz reiniciado el terminal? - @jeancarlos733

Comment: pues lo cerre y lo volví a abrir

Comment: @jeancarlos733 - Solo cerrar no sirve... tienes que salir completamente del terminal... o reinicia tu ordenador completo

Comment: ya lo reinicie y aun sale igual :(

Comment: @jeancarlos733 - pues es raro que no te funcione... Vamos por paso... abre tu terminal introduce `cd ~` luego introduce `sudo vi .bash_profile` pulsas la tecla `i` introduce `export PS1="\W \$ "`  pulsa la tecla `esc` y introduces `:wq` luego sales (`salir`) completamente de terminal y abres de nuevo terminal...

Comment: no funciona sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

## Solución probada en: macOS Mojave

Si sólo quieres cambiar el nombre de la Mac y sin reiniciarla porque el disco duro está cifrado.

> menú Apple [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] > Preferencias del Sistema > Compartir

Ahí aparece el nombre del ordenador y le das en editar.

Sólo cierra el terminal y lo vuelves a abrir.